# is using CountDownTimer to add styles every few milliseconds a correct approach?

Tags: android

I have an audio track playing and the array of words in the track where each word has corresponding starting time:

```
HashMap<String, Float> words = new HashMap<>();
words.put("This", 11.258);
words.put("is", 11.733);
words.put("some", 11.733);
```

I also have this text displayed in a TextView. Whenever a word is pronounced in the audio track, I want that word highlighted. At the moment the only solution I can think of is to run `CountDownTimer` every few milliseconds and highlight currently played word there, something like this:

```
 new CountDownTimer(30000, 4) {

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        // remove previos word highlighting
        ...
        // highlight current word
        Spannable spannableText = new SpannableString(tv.getText());
        spannableText.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.LTGRAY), startOffset, endOffset, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        tv.setText(spannableText);
     }

     public void onFinish() {

     }
  }.start();
```

Is this approach OK or maybe there are better approaches to implement the functionality I described? Maybe using something from MediaPlayer?

Comment: Thanks, how's handler going to be a better approach?

Comment: I posted my answer below:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to define your own thread for the Timer, so you
sidestep all the issues of thread management, letting the system handle it.

Here is the handler implementation:

```
    //updated the screen when we are testing for connectivity and errors.
private Handler handlerHighlightWords = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

                ...
        // highlight current word
        Spannable spannableText = new SpannableString(tv.getText());
        spannableText.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.LTGRAY), startOffset, endOffset, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        tv.setText(spannableText);
        handlerMessageText.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, 1000);
    }
};

    //runnable to to feed to handler.
final Runnable handlerRunnableMessage = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Spannable spannableText = new SpannableString(tv.getText());
        spannableText.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.LTGRAY), startOffset, endOffset, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        tv.setText(spannableText);


    }
};
```

Then once you click a button:

```
handlerMessageText.post(handlerRunnableMessage);
```

Comment: thanks! Can you please explain why this approach is better than using `CountDownTimer`? I don't create thread for `CountDownTimer` I run it from the main application thread.

Comment: I created another class for another project that used the base code of the CountDownTimer.  As you can see, the countdown timer also uses a handler.  https://github.com/techartist/SixtySecondYogaFree/blob/master/src/com/webnation/sixtysecondyogafree/CountDownTimerWithPause.java.  I think a handler is a perfect choice for your app - I don't thing you need to go with a countdown timer.